# Using Time Picker to make alarm clock

Tags: android, time, timepicker

So what I am trying to do is to make an alarm clock. I am having trouble getting the current time and get the timepicker's time to compare them. If you could help me out a bit just getting the timepicker's time and the current time in the same kind of measurement would be great.

Thanks a ton =)
Here is my code:

```
public class AlarmlockActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    TimePicker tp;
    Button set;
    long currentTime;
    long alarmTime;
    long alarmHourmil;
    DigitalClock dc;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tpAlarmTime);
    set = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSet);
    dc = (DigitalClock) findViewById(R.id.digitalClock1);
    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    set.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.bSet:
        break;
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that extracting *hour* and *minutes* from current time is enough to get *"timepicker's time and the current time in the same kind of measurement*.

If that's the case you can use `Calendar` class ([see docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)) to extract info about current time. Here's an example code that assumes, you want to use default `Locale` and `TimeZone`, if that's not the case please [refer to other](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28java.util.Locale%29) `Calendar.getInstance()` methods.

```
// Get Calendar object with current date and time (assumes default Locale and TimeZone).
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

// Retrieve info about current time.
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

// Compare with values selected in TimePicker
if (tp.getCurrentHour().intValue() == hour) { // similar applies to 'minute'
    // do whatever you want
}
```